# How to forbid Git messing with line endings while retaining diff capability?

Tags: git, github

According to https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#per-repository-settings I can use `.gitattributes` to force a line-ending-handling policy.

I want to tell Git "don't touch my line endings, I'll decide the ending of each line in each file myself".

I tried following `.gitattributes` file:

```
* binary
```

Unfortunately now I couldn't view diffs of the changes anymore (in Github for Windows).

How can I force the "Don't ever change line endings, regardless of file type" policy, while retaining the ability to view diffs for text files?

Comment: Try `git diff -a`

Comment: @ElpieKay I want to use the graphical diff in Github for Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the policy for the entire repo, why not just `git config core.autocrlf false`?

btw, if you prefer attributes for some reason, the correct one would be `-text`.  (Alejandro suggests `-crlf` but that's only there for backwards compatibility.)

Comment: Isn't this for specifying the user-level preference?

Comment: @Aivar - In that the config settings don't port with the repo, I suppose you can look at it that way. It's still how many projects manage the autocrlf settings.  It seems to me that saying "leave it to the developer to determine line endings" implies that it *is* a matter of user-level preference; but regardless, I've added an attribute-based alternative as well.  (The `binary` attribute you tried just isn't the right one; you could make it work, but it's not what that attribute is supposed to mean.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this gitattributes file instead:

```
# Ignore all differences in line endings
*        -crlf
```